# Marker error in onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android

I want to set marker on my current location, I put marker in onLocationChanged but it shows error on mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

[image]

Comment: can you show your code & full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: you can only use map after onmapready is being called, probably it is null